# Getting error while trying to integrate cloud firestore with flutter windows platforms

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, cmake, flutter-windows, flutter-build

Recently cloud firestore has extended its support for windows, now Iam trying to integrate cloud firestore package with my flutter windows platform project. in debug mode Iam not getting any error. but if iam tring tocan anyone please guide me to solve this problem. take build iam getting the folling error:

[image]

Can anyone please guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message to be in the question post as **text**, not linked as image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. Please, (re-)read [ask] and edit your question post accordingly.

Comment: I quickly checked with the engineering team, and they suspect this may be a bug in the SDK. Can you open an issue on the repo here: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire If you include a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there, that'll make it faster for them to reproduce and thus fix the issue.